# Opencv:convexityDefects on largest contour gives error

Tags: python, opencv, convexity-defects

I am getting this error :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (hpoints > 0) in cv::convexityDefects, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp, line 284
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PycharmProjects/ComputerVisionAgain/Image Segmentation/hand_blk/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    hull_defects=cv2.convexityDefects(sorted_cnts[0],hull)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp:284: error: (-215) hpoints > 0 in function cv::convexityDefects
```

when I try to get the convexityDefects of the largest contour of the image.
This is the code I am using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('blk_hand.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(gray,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_,contours,h=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
sorted_cnts=sorted(contours,key=cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)
hull=cv2.convexHull(sorted_cnts[0])
hull_defects=cv2.convexityDefects(sorted_cnts[0],hull)
cv2.drawContours(img,[hull],-1,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.drawContours(img,sorted_cnts[0],-1,(0,255,0),3)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: This is the original image]

[image: This is threshed image]

[image: This is convex hulled image on largest contour]

Answer (score 6):

`cv2.convexHull` returns convex hull as a set of points by default (**returnPoints** argument is responsible for this, defaulted to **True**,  [docs here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexhull)). But the `cv2.convexityDefects` function, according to [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexitydefects), expects 2nd argument to be *indices of the contour points that make the hull*.

So just change

```
hull=cv2.convexHull(sorted_cnts[0])
```

to

```
hull=cv2.convexHull(sorted_cnts[0], returnPoints=False)
```

so `hull` will contain indices of original `sorted_cnts[0]` contour that make the convex hull.

BTW, in this case you still can obtain the hull as a set of points by doing `sorted_cnts[0][hull]`.

Comment: Currently, under OpenCV 3.x the BTW code should be: `sorted_cnts[0][cnt[[ h[0] for h in hull]]]` as this is yet another case of OpenCV having what appear to be extra single-element array-nesses.